# How To Select All Rows In A Table By Querying Data In Another Table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, optimization

I have 3 SQLite tables that must be queried to obtain the final data. 

I must select everything in *ItemAppearance* where *DisplayType* == 4
Then take the corresponding number from the *ID* field and
Select all rows in *ItemModifiedAppearance* where *ItemAppearanceID* == Previous Number
Then take the corresponding number *ItemID* field and
Select all rows in *ItemSearchName* where *ID* == Previous Number
Finally, I can retrieve a large list of all the *Display_lang* values that I need.

Graphically: [image]

What's the best / fastest / most efficient way to get this list of strings?

Comment: I don't know how to say it in text other than the paragraph above the image. Sorry Tim. It's a single image. Not image(s).

Comment: The images you included don't really help your question. Please delete them, and instead include sample data, as text, for all the tables involved in your question.

Comment: @Selzier . . . MySQL <> SQLite.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, but I'm guessing here [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) is your friend:

```
SELECT *
FROM ItemAppearance ia LEFT JOIN 
     ItemModifiedAppearance im
     ON ia.ID==im.ItemAppearanceID JOIN
     ItemSearchName isn
     ON ia.ID==isn.ID
WHERE ia.DisplayType = 4;
```

So that just gets all 3 databases, where all the id's match, but only the ones that are in *ItemAppearance* that are of *DataType* 4.

Hopefully that helps, or makes sense, or was even in the ballpark of your question. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I write this solution, if there is a more optimized way of achieving this, please let me know:

```
SELECT  itemsearchname.ID, itemsearchname.Display_lang, itemappearance.DisplayType
FROM ((itemappearance
INNER JOIN itemmodifiedappearance ON itemappearance.ID = itemmodifiedappearance.ItemAppearanceID)
INNER JOIN itemsearchname ON itemmodifiedappearance.ItemID = itemsearchname.ID)
WHERE DisplayType == 4;
```